# Can't access bloc in showModal context in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I wrap my *scafflod* with `dart BlocProvider<ABloc,AState>`
but when I use **showDialog** func and **showDialog** I want to access ABloc from context or **BlocBuilder**
doesn't contain bloc and throw error
is there a way to access bloc in this situatuion
(in my dialog I show text filed to get user name so I want to access bloc)

```
class MyHomePageState extends StateLessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        lazy: false,
        create: (context) => EditColorBloc(context.bloc<RetrieveColorBloc>()),
        child: MainScafold());
  }
}
```

```
class MainScafold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("sina"),
      ),
      floatingActionButton:FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () => showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (ctx) {
              // show dialog and use 
              // context o BlocBuilder to access 
              // EditColorBloc
              // throw error BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does 
              // not contain a Cubit of type EditColorBloc
              }
           )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE v6.1.0**

(Credit to [@Sebastian Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288587/sebastian-denis))

`context.bloc` was deprecated in favor of provider's `context.read`, `context.watch`, and `context.select`. In the below code, just change `context.bloc<TestBloc>` to `context.read<TestBloc>`

---

You shouldn't use a `BlocBuilder` to wrap the `Dialog`. Reason being is that you're (most likely) not rebuilding the whole `Dialog` whenever a change occurs. Another, more important, reason is that the context in which your `Dialog` is being built doesn't contain your `bloc`, so you need to inject your `bloc` instance into the `Dialog`'s `context`.

Instead, use `BlocProvider.value` and set the `value` parameter to `BlocProvider.of(context)` (aka `context.bloc()` ), and make sure the context is not the `showDailog` 's method context, but the context in the original `build` method.

Here is a working example. You just have to change the `TestBloc` or `TestState` etc to your own `Bloc` instances:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<TestBloc>(
        create: (context) => TestBloc(InitTestState()),
        child: Scaffold(
            body: BlocBuilder<TestBloc, TestState>(
              builder: (context, state) => Center(
                child: FlatButton(
                  child: Text("Show Dialog"), 
                  onPressed: () => showDialog(
                      context: context, 

                      // Relavent code change here
                      builder: (ctx) => BlocProvider<TestBloc>.value(
                        value: context.bloc<TestBloc>(), 

                        child: Dialog(
                          child: FlatButton(
                            child: Text("Notify bloc"),
                            onPressed: () => context
                                .bloc<TestBloc>()
                                .add(TestEvent()),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
            ),
          ),
        )));
```

Comment: thanks man , i use dialog context but i think dialog context not contain scafold context and use MaterialApp context

Comment: another my problem was  using BlocProvider istead of BlocProvider.value

Comment: There was a change in context.bloc -> https://bloclibrary.dev/#/migration?id=v610